# Rails not permitting payload from JSON schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema, jsonb

I am trying to figure out why my rails app is not permitting my attributes and have run out of ideas.

I have products in my database (model Product) and they have a collection of standard attributes that apply to all products. I have an additional JSONB column called dynamic_attributes that is specific to different types of product. Due to this, I am currently using STI.

If I attempt to edit an individual record, I get an error regarding unpermitted parameters (the JSON parameters I am trying to update/patch from the edit form). If I remove the .permit section and just permit! everything then I get no errors and everything updates but obviously this isn't ideal.

Lock subclass for STI

```
class Lock < Product
  serialize :dynamic_attributes, JsonbSerializers
  store_accessor :dynamic_attributes, :kind, :interface
  validates :kind, presence: true

  def json_schema
    Rails.root.join('app', 'models', 'schemas', 'lock_category.json')
  end
end
```

which references the following JSON schema for the product type in question:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [ "kind" ],
  "properties": {
    "kind": { 
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["Cable", "Chain", "Folding", "Frame", "Part", "Padlock", "U-Lock", "U-Lock+Cable"]
    },
    "interface": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["Key", "Combination", "Smart"]
    }
  }
}
```

Products Controller

```
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.update!(product_params)
    redirect_to @product
  end

private
  
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).
    permit(
      :type,
      :vendor,
      :description,
      :cost,
      :msrp,
      dynamic_attributes: [
        :kind,
        :interface
      ]
    )
  end
end
```

and the edit form is pretty standard with the following section for updating the dynamic_attributes:

```
  <% @product[:dynamic_attributes].each do |k,v| %>
    <%= f.label k.to_sym %>  
    <%= f.text_field k.to_sym, :value => v %>
    <br />
  <% end %>
```

If I were to guess (all I have left at this point, I think it is probably something between loading the information from the database into the edit field and then back again.

The log from the attempted PATCH:

```
Started PATCH "/products/0c092119-601c-4dbb-b05b-3ad5ac638631" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-03-09 12:41:06 -0600
Processing by ProductsController#update as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "product"=>{"vendor"=>"Vendor", "description"=>"First Lock", "cost"=>"37.5", "msrp"=>"74.99", "type"=>"Lock", "kind"=>"U-Lock", "interface"=>"Smart"}, "commit"=>"Update Product", "id"=>"0c092119-601c-4dbb-b05b-3ad5ac638631"}
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "0c092119-601c-4dbb-b05b-3ad5ac638631"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:23:in `update'
Unpermitted parameters: :kind, :interface. Context: { controller: ProductsController, action: update, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00007fbba812f500>, params: {"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "product"=>{"vendor"=>"Vendor", "description"=>"First Lock", "cost"=>"37.5", "msrp"=>"74.99", "type"=>"Lock", "kind"=>"U-Lock", "interface"=>"Smart"}, "commit"=>"Update Product", "controller"=>"products", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"0c092119-601c-4dbb-b05b-3ad5ac638631"} }
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:24:in `update'
  Product Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."vpn" = $1 AND "products"."id" != $2 AND "products"."vendor" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["vpn", "453"], ["id", "0c092119-601c-4dbb-b05b-3ad5ac638631"], ["vendor", "Vendor"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:24:in `update'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:24:in `update'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/0c092119-601c-4dbb-b05b-3ad5ac638631
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms | Allocations: 5365)
```

Comment: add the log from the put/patch call that has the raw parameters please.

Comment: Please add the Error Message as well.

Comment: `kind`, and `interface` are not permitted because you are stating that they should be nested under `dynamic_attributes` but in the request they are not nested.  Maybe try changing this `f.text_field k.to_sym` to `f.text_field "dyanmic_attributes[#{k}]"`?

Comment: **DO NOT use serialize with native JSONB columns.** Or really at all. The conversion is automatically handled by the database driver so what you actually storing isn't JSON objects, arrays etc. Its a string containing JSON that will not be queryable. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @engineersmnky who had the answer:

kind, and interface are not permitted because you are stating that they should be nested under dynamic_attributes but in the request they are not nested. Maybe try changing this

```
f.text_field k.to_sym to f.text_field "dyanmic_attributes[#{k}]"
```

So I updated my code accordingly to:

```
  <% @product[:dynamic_attributes].each do |k,v| %>
    <%= f.label k.to_sym %>  
    <%= f.text_field "dynamic_attributes[#{k}]", :value => v %>
  <% end %>
```